# Matlab string operation

Tags: string, matlab, binary

I have converted a string to binary as follows

```
message='hello my name is kamran';
messagebin=dec2bin(message);
```

Is there any method for storing it in array?

Comment: `messagebin` is already an array of char. What exactly do you want? Give an example of an output

Comment: I didn't know you could do dec2bin on a string like that in the first place.. octave for example complains big time.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure of what you want to do here, but if you need to concatenate the rows of the binary representation (which is a matrix of numchars times bits_per_char), this is the code:

```
message = 'hello my name is kamran';
messagebin = dec2bin(double(message));
linearmessagebin = reshape(messagebin',1,numel(messagebin));
```

Please note that the double conversion returns your ASCII code. I do not have access to a Matlab installation here, but for example octave complains about the code you provided in the original question.

**NOTE**

As it was kindly pointed out to me, you have to transpose the `messagebin` before "serializing" it, in order to have the correct result.

Comment: actually you need to transpose `messagebin` before linearizing into a vector: `reshape(messagebin',1,[]);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result as numeric matrix, try:

```
>> str = 'hello world';
>> b = dec2bin(double(str),8) - '0'
b =
     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     1
     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1
     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     0
```

Each row corresponds to a character. You can easily reshape it into to sequence of 0,1